# Dynamically Start Event on File Input

Tags: javascript, forms, file, file-upload, input

I'm looking for a way to dynamically "click" the browse button of a `input type="file".` I have a button that contains an onclick event which I'd like to click the browse button of the `input type="file",` then an onchange event of the `input type="file"` will submit the form once the file is selected. I'm not sure how to "click" the `input type="file"` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is call the `click` function of the `input` element from the desired element's click handler.

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<div id="clickme">Click Me to Open File Browser</div>

document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById('files').click(); 
}
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/5ckx5/) to show it in action.